# Multiple domains pointed to single WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am on WordPress (single site) using the Transposh plugin to have an English and Spanish version of my site. I want to have an English domain (let's say www.english.com) for the English version, and a Spanish domain (spanish.com) for the Spanish version. I have set up spanish.com to forward with english.com with domain masking.

I have also added the following code to wp-config.php.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'spanish.com') !== false) :
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://spanish.com');
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://spanish.com');
endif;
```

In functions.php:

```
// If coming from spanish domain, make language spanish, regardless of query string
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'spanish.com') !== false) { 
    $my_transposh_plugin->target_language = 'es';
}
```

.htaccess:

```
# This sees if the URL is from english.com and has lang=es 
# in the query string. If it does, redirect to spanish.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=es [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.english\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://spanish.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The only issue is that the changes have broken all of the autogenerated file links. CSS/JS/IMG links now go to http://spanish.com/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css. Because of the domain masking, that link would go to an html page with the css file embedded in a frame on the page. What is the best way to fix this?

EDIT: (My edit was wrong)

Comment: What happens when you set `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` to `'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert When I do that, all the assets load fine. The problem is that all of the links on the page go to english.com?lang=es. When clicking on that from the spanish site, it tries to redirect to spanish.com?lang=es and gets caught in a redirect loop. spanish.com however works fine. Maybe a change to the htaccess rewrite rule to redirect to spanish.com instead of spanish.com?lang=es?

Comment: How are you creating those links?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Those are all links created by WP (eg, menus, the_permalink(), etc). The plugin adds ?lang=es to the end of all links.

Comment: Do you need the query string if the different languages are on different domains?  Would it not make more sense to just check the domain and server the correct content that way?  IE, if domain is www.spanish.com, serve spanish content.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert That would be fine (which is why those 3 lines were added to functions.php), but the plugin works by using the query string. I don't think there's a way to change that and it would be too time consuming to change plugins for this.